# NsDateFormatter format the date

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can i this format this date ?

2/24/2017 11:13:43 AM

i tried this code but not worked

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdDate];
```

Comment: Please show the output you got, and explain how it differs from the output you want. Is the problem that you didn't get the "AM/PM" part? What?

Comment: Maybe `createdDate` is `nil`.

Comment: createdDate : 2/24/2017 11:13:43 AM

Comment: So you claim. But I tried your formatter and it works just fine (e.g. instead of `createdDate`, use `[Date new]`). So show how `createdDate` is declared and how it is set.

Comment: Are you trying to convert an `NSString` into an `NSDate` or are you trying to convert an `NSDate` into an `NSString`. Your code tries to do the latter but your question implies you want the former. Either way, the date format in your code doesn't match the format you ask about in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the dateformate. You need to 'a' into formater.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Output:

```
Printing description of stringDate:
02/25/2017 09:56:42 AM
```

You can see more about [dateFormate](https://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/).

Cheers